# Connection Timeout using LdapExtLoginModule

Tags: java, jboss, active-directory, ldap, jaas

I am attempting to authenticate users against an existing LDAP server (Active-Directory) using the LdapExtLoginModule provided by JBoss 4.2.3.  I have had some success connecting, but the LDAP server seems to be somewhat slow, and at certain times of the day I get consistent timeout issues.  I don't mind making my users wait for a while to be authenticated, but I haven't been able to increase the timeout duration.  See below for a list of settings I have tried in this vein.  Note that this is a web application built using Seam 2.

Here is the relevant section of login-config.xml

```
<application-policy name="LdapToActiveDirectory">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">

      <module-option name="debug">true</module-option>
      <module-option name="trace">true</module-option>

      <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url">ldap://domain.mycompany.net:389/</module-option>

      <module-option name="bindDN">CN=rsauth - RS Authentication Binding,OU=Service Accounts,OU=City,OU=US,DC=Domain,DC=MyCompany,DC=net</module-option>
      <module-option name="bindCredential">asdfjkl;</module-option>

      <module-option name="baseCtxDN">DC=Domain,DC=MyCompany,DC=net</module-option>
      <module-option name="baseFilter">(sAMAccountName={0})</module-option>

      <module-option name="rolesCtxDN">DC=Domain,DC=MyCompany,DC=net</module-option>
      <module-option name="roleFilter">(sAMAccountName={0})</module-option>
      <module-option name="roleAttributeID">memberOf</module-option>
      <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN">true</module-option>
      <module-option name="roleNameAttributeID">cn</module-option>

      <module-option name="searchTimeLimit">100000</module-option>

      <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>

      <module-option name="java.naming.referral">follow</module-option>
    </login-module>
  </authentication>
</application-policy>
```

Notice the "searchTimeLimit" option is set to 100,000 milliseconds.  However, when a timeout does occur, it seems to do so after only 20 seconds - way below the time limit specified.  Here is an example stack trace and log excerpt:

```
2011-07-08 12:50:31,692 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule:122] initialize, instance=@1270783
2011-07-08 12:50:31,692 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule:125] Security domain: LdapToActiveDirectory
2011-07-08 12:50:31,692 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule:166] login
2011-07-08 12:50:52,710 DEBUG [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule:216] Bad password for username=myuser
javax.naming.CommunicationException: domain.mycompany.net:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:210)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:118)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1580)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2652)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:293)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:175)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:136)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:66)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:134)
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule.constructInitialLdapContext(LdapExtLoginModule.java:544)
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule.createLdapInitContext(LdapExtLoginModule.java:342)
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule.validatePassword(LdapExtLoginModule.java:232)
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:210)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
    at org.jboss.seam.security.Identity.authenticate(Identity.java:344)
    at org.jboss.seam.security.Identity.authenticate(Identity.java:332)
    at org.jboss.seam.security.Identity.login(Identity.java:259)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:348)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:321)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:296)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:253)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:466)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.createSocket(Connection.java:352)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:187)
    ... 91 more
2011-07-08 12:50:52,913 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule:240] abort
```

In addition to the "searchTimeLimit" module option mentioned above, I have also tried setting some properties as command line arguments (reference [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/newstuff/readtimeout.html)):

```
-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout=100000
-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout=100000
```

These also seemed to have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that LDAP clients cannot override the period of time specified by the server for LDAP requests. The directory server administrator might have specified a smaller time period associated with connections and/or requests. In other words, servers may specify a maximum time limit and/or size limit for searches. This information comes from [RFC4511](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511). In the case given, it appears that the transport connection itself exceeded the amount of time given, or the server failed to respond, or something else happened. This would be unrelated to the search time limit, which as noted above might be capped by the server, irrespective of values specified by the client.

Comment: In the case that the transport connection is at issue, do you have any recommendations?  I was going to try adding a retry loop (by manually overriding the authentication code), but is there a transport-level timeout that I should be looking for?

Comment: Two things: 1) are you using SSL? I'm no expert on JNDI (JNDI is a terrible idea - I thought that even when I worked for Sun), but I read somewhere that that connect.timeout does not work when the connection security type is SSL, but don't take my word for that. 2) are you certain the com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout property is set at the time the connection is attempted?

Comment: The more I get into this, the more I think your mention of a size limit/time limit on the server is the problem.  Either way, I think I have found a solution that will work in my case.  Because of the way my company's directory is laid out, and because of the number of accounts that the directory holds, it looks like the search is too expensive and time consuming.  Instead of using LdapExtLoginModule to try to "simplify" the LDAP access, I am now using the java.naming.directory package directly, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389746/ldap-java-library/389807#389807).

Comment: This lets me get at the intended user record much more directly, avoiding some of the expense of the search.  So far, the authentication attempts are consistently not timing out.